# Ubuntu, how to unmount remote shared drive if the share is down?

Tags: mount

I have a remote share on another computer which is currently down.

The command I used to mount is:

```
sudo mount //10.10.100.100/files /home/user/remoteDir/ -o username=user,password=pass,dir_mode=777,file_mode=777
```

I cannot unmount through the gui as it says the device is busy, because it is down and I cannot find the correct syntax to unmount it from the terminal as I always get some error.

The reason I want to unmount is because the system is running really slow with the server being down and I am hoping mounting will fix it, and I cannot restart the system at the moment.

Thanks.

Updates:

I tried umount and smbmount for the share and keep getting command not found?

I tried umount again and this time the command work, but I got an error saying device is busy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo umount -l /home/user/remoteDir/
```

Seems to have worked.

I found the solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/475288

Are there any issues or alternatives to using the -l switch?

Comment: The `-l` switch is for lazy unmounting. It waits for all operations to finish. However, that might be a random remote terminal sitting there, delaying it indefinitely. It works without `-l` too, but maybe check that no services are doing important work on said share

Comment: The drive comes right back after a reboot.